# How can I use the for loop with special seq

Tags: r, arrays, for-loop, seq

I want to make a for loop where the seq is an array's elements.

So like I have an array like this:

```
int <- array(c(30,60,150,300,450,1500))
```

and I wanted that the first j is 30, second is 60 ...etc.

But when I obviosly tried this:

```
for (j in int)
```

this did not work.

How can I solve this?

Comment: You may use `seq(30,  length.out =2, by = 30)`. regarding the values 150, 300, and 450, 1500, the pattern is not clear

Comment: I really tried to explain my problem properly but it's hard for me. So I want that my "j" in my for loop will be the first time 30 and the second time 60 and after that 150. So I create an array for these numbers.

Comment: If you use `for(j in int) print(j)` it prints that value

Comment: I want a sequence where the elements of the array are taken up by j. There are cloud base heights in the array. And in the first case, I examine when the cloud base height is 30 meters, so then j = 30 etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could use `embed`

```
m1 <- embed(c(int, int), length(int))[seq_along(int),]
m1[lower.tri(m1)] <- NA
lapply(asplit(m1, 1), function(x) rev(x[!is.na(x)]))
#[[1]]
#[1]   30   60  150  300  450 1500

#[[2]]
#[1]   60  150  300  450 1500

#[[3]]
#[1]  150  300  450 1500

#[[4]]
#[1]  300  450 1500

#[[5]]
#[1]  450 1500

#[[6]]
#[1] 1500
```

---

Or using a `for` loop

```
out <- vector('list', length(int))
for(i in seq_along(int)) out[[i]] <- if(i == 1) int else int[-seq(i -1)]
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for this?

```
Map(function(x) int[x:length(int)], seq(int))
# [[1]]
# [1]   30   60  150  300  450 1500
# 
# [[2]]
# [1]   60  150  300  450 1500
# 
# [[3]]
# [1]  150  300  450 1500
# 
# [[4]]
# [1]  300  450 1500
# 
# [[5]]
# [1]  450 1500
# 
# [[6]]
# [1] 1500
```

Or this

```
Map(function(x) int[x:length(int)], 1:3)
# [[1]]
# [1]   30   60  150  300  450 1500
# 
# [[2]]
# [1]   60  150  300  450 1500
# 
# [[3]]
# [1]  150  300  450 1500
```

Anyway, the second argument of `Map` are the starting indices.

Answer (score 0):

Another base R option

```
> lapply(-seq_along(int), tail, x = c(NA, int))
[[1]]
[1]   30   60  150  300  450 1500

[[2]]
[1]   60  150  300  450 1500

[[3]]
[1]  150  300  450 1500

[[4]]
[1]  300  450 1500

[[5]]
[1]  450 1500

[[6]]
[1] 1500
```